# Why can't I do foreach (var Item in DataTable.Rows)?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, foreach, datarow

Is there a reason why I can't do the following:

```
foreach (var Item in DataTable.Rows) {
```

rather than having to do

```
foreach (DataRow Item in DataTable.Rows) {
```

I would have thought this was possible, like it is on other datatypes. For example:

```
foreach (var Employee in Staff) { // string[] Staff etc...
```

When I try the first foreach loop, I get the the error **CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'**.

Why can't the compiler figure out that .Rows returns a collections of DataRows?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Rows` effectively returns `IEnumerable` (`DataRowCollection`), so the compiler can only pick `object` as the type for `var`. Use `Rows.Cast<DataRow>` if you want to use `var`.

`Cast` is defined on [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx), so you have to include System.Linq.

Comment: Were datatables before generics?

Comment: @Arnis: Absolutely, DataTable has been in since 1.0.

Comment: So - i guess that's the real reason. Ty Jon for clarification. :)

Answer (score 25):

Brian is absolutely right about the reason for this, but there's a simpler way of avoiding it: use [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx):

```
foreach (var row in DataTable.AsEnumerable())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a nifty solution :) I have kept the Accepted Answer as Brian's but will be using yours. It's time a read up about Enumerables a bit more...

Comment: I'd say the real solution to the problem would be to not use var in this instance...

Comment: @ck: Agreed, but it's worth knowing about `AsEnumerable` in order to tie in with other LINQ methods.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't the compiler figure out that .Rows returns a collections of DataRows?

Because of the way the DataTable Rows (DataRowCollection) works with enumeration, and also partly to do with  the way `foreach` works, and how ancient it all is.

First a bit about `foreach`:

`foreach` isn't really a thing; it's more like a language shortcut for a while loop that gets an enumerator on an object and repeatedly calls `MoveNext`, `MoveNext`, `MoveNext` ... until `MoveNext` returns false, at which point it stops looping. The first thing the loop body of the while does is call `Current` on the enumerator, and and loads the response into the variable you specified in the `foreach` declaration. The body of the loop you wrote is placed into the body of the while loop, after this first bit. To you it looks like `foreach` is a real loop. In reality it's like a find/replace exercise by the compiler. Lots of things in C# are this way - new features and syntax reductions are just a find/replace way of doing the code the old way.

To be `foreach`able a class doesn't have to implement any interface or be any particular type, it simply has to have a method called `GetEnumerator()` that returns *"something that can be enumerated"*.

*"Something that can be enumerated"* is defined as "a class that has a `bool MoveNext()` method and a `Current` property that returns any kind of object". Again, this *"something that can be enumerated"* doesn't have to implement any interface, or be any particular type; it just have to have one method and one property with certain name(s) and particular signature(s). The whole thing is like magic and there are no constraints on it anywhere:

```
public class ForeachableThing{
  public EnumeratorSchmenumerator GetEnumerator(){
    return new EnumeratorSchmenumerator();
  }
}

public class EnumeratorSchmenumerator{
  public DateTime Current {
    get{ return DateTime.Now; }
  }
  public bool MoveNext() {
    return DateTime.Now.Hour == 0;
  }
}
```

You can foreach this millions of times to get the current time, between midnight and 1am. The enumeration doesn't need to have a collection or move anywhere; it just has to return values as asked and return true or false when told to move. I outline this just in case you think "but surely something would have to implement some IEnumerable.. and that would mean there's some typing in there somewhere and..". No - ever since datatable was invented it's been possible to enumerate things purely based on whether there is a certain method/property on them or not

---

Skipping forward to `DataTable.Rows`; this is a collection; a `DataRowCollection` to be precise. It does implement the `IEnumerable` interface by dint of the fact that it inherits from `InternalDataCollectionBase`, which implements `IEnumerable` - but that in itself is only an interface that states "The class must have a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns an `IEnumerator`", and `IEnumerator` is an interface that enforces "must have a `Current` property that returns `object` and a `MoveNext()` that returns `bool`".

It wasn't necessary to implement these interfaces to be `foreach`able, but it helps..

..and maybe you then spotted it: implementing `IEnumerator` requires that the `Current` property be an `object`.

This is a compiler error:

```
public class EnumeratorSchmenumerator : IEnumerator //look! new bit!
{
  public DateTime Current {
    get{ return DateTime.Now; }
  }
  public bool MoveNext() {
    return DateTime.Now.Hour == 0;
  }
}
```

> 'EnumeratorSchmenumerator' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerator.Current'.
> [The existing] 'EnumeratorSchmenumerator.Current' cannot implement 'IEnumerator.Current' because it does not have the matching return type of 'object'

So in choosing to have the `DataRowCollection` implement `IEnumerable`, they were forced to write a `.GetEnumerator()` method that returned an `IEnumerator`, and that in turn forces the `Current` to be an `object`

There's a `DataRow` inside that object, but the compiler doesn't know that, so it types the `var` as `object`.

When you say `foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)` the code C# writes behind the scenes to expand the `foreach` will include a cast to `DataRow`.

With the `var` form, it's like you wrote `foreach(object r in dt.Rows)`