# "var" type inference in C#

Tags: c#, .net, type-inference, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does var evaluate to System.Object in “foreach (var row in table.Rows)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786727/why-does-var-evaluate-to-system-object-in-foreach-var-row-in-table-rows)

I was rather suprised to discovered the following today....

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();


// the following compiles correctly
foreach (DataRow field in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(field["ColumnName"]);
}


// the following does not compile as 'var' is of type 'object'
foreach (var field in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    // Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
    Console.WriteLine(field["ColumnName"]);
}
```

Whats going on here?

Is this a type inference failure? And if so, what causes it?

Or is it part of the defined behaviour or `var`? And if so, why?

I thought the idea of `var` was that you could use it anywhere in a variable declaration/initialisation *without changing behaviour*.

Comment: [exact duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325777/why-cant-i-do-foreach-var-item-in-datatable-rows) Basically Rows is a `DataRowCollection`, so the compiler picks up `Object`, not `DataRow`

Comment: `DataRowCollection.GetEnumerator()` returns `IEnumerator`. The type of `IEnumerator.Current` is `object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point here is not var, but the foreach loop. The foreach loop can optionally cast the iterator in addition to iterating itself.

So you can do the following:

```
List<object> test = new List<object>();
test.Add(1);
test.Add(2);
test.Add(3);
foreach( int i in test ){
  i.Dump();
}
```

So even if the list is of type object, it can be casted to int on the fly inside the foreach.

Comment: I did not know this, thanks. I was wondering why the iterator didn't require an explicit cast in the first example.

Comment: Please note that if you do this, you will get a null reference exception if the type to the left of the variable name does not match the actual type of the object in the enumeration.  You can't use it to go `foreach(DerivedType derived in ListOfBaseTypes)` and expect it to work properly unless everything in your `ListOfBaseTypes` is of type `DerivedType`

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable.Rows` returns `System.Data.DataRowCollection` which is a subclass of `InternalDataCollectionBase`.

The `GetEnumerator` memthod on this returns `IEnumerator`, rather than `IEnumerator<DataRows>`.

Hence the only type information available is that it returns `object`, so when you specify you are enumerating `DataRow` you are adding your own cast, which `var` does not.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is that `foreach(SomeType thing in SomeCollection)` doesn't just iterate through the collection, it also attempts a cast to SomeType for each item as it iterates. But with var there's nothing to cast to.