# Use of C# var for implicit typing of System.Data.Datarow

Tags: c#, datarow, implicit-typing

```
foreach (var row in table.Rows)
{
     DoSomethingWith(row);
}
```

Assuming that I'm working with a standard `System.Data.DataTable` (which has a collection of `System.Data.DataRow` objects), the variable 'row' above resolves as an `object` type, not a `System.Data.DataRow`.

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
     DoSomethingWith(row);
}
```

Works as I would expect. Is there a particular reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why can't I do foreach (var Item in DataTable.Rows)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325777/why-cant-i-do-foreach-var-item-in-datatable-rows) or [Why does var evaluate to System.Object in “foreach (var row in table.Rows)”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786727/why-does-var-evaluate-to-system-object-in-foreach-var-row-in-table-rows?lq=1).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's because `Rows` is `DataRowCollection`, which in turn is `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which means that type inferred will be `object`.

When you explicitly state type in `foreach`, you instruct c# to add cast to each call, which is why it works.

Answer (score 5):

An implicit cast happens. Also note that an **InvalidCastException** can be thrown if the cast isn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

`table.Rows` is a DataRowCollection which is `IEnumberable` ( and not `IEnumerable<T>`, T being `DataRow`), so it is not strongly typed to a `DataRow`, but a object i.e it is a collection of objects.

There is a `DataTable` extensions which you can use though - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx

```
foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

foreach (var row in dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>())
{

}
```

To use Rows.Cast you have to use System.Linq.